# Support for DEVPATH

Tags: .net, gac

I have a question about support for DEVPATH (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cskzh7h6.aspx) in the future. As I have read Microsoft considered deprecating it in the past but decided not to. Do you know if there are plans of deprecating it in .NET 4.0 or further? Or is it going to be supported?

Thank You

Kuzu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This came up on a course I did with Wintellect recently, who have quite close links with MS. Apparently no, there's no longer plans to deprecate it as it's too useful for development purposes.

Link to [John Robbins' recent blog article mentioning it](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx) (about 2/3 of the way through).

> By the way, if you search for DEVPATH in any internet search engine one of the top entries 
>   is an out of date blog entry by Suzanne Cook saying Microsoft was getting rid of DEVPATH. That is no longer true. As with any blog entry, look at the date on Suzanne's blog: 2003. That's the equivalent of 1670 in internet years.